# htaccess redirect from asp to php with variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, asp-classic

How can I redirect the pages ASP to the new PHPpages ?

Example:

**from** /pages/fauna/fauna.asp?IdF=1

**redirect to** /pages/fauna/fauna?id=1

I tried with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^IdF=1$
RewriteRule ^pages/fauna/fauna\.asp$ /pages/fauna/fauna?id=1 [R=301,L]
```

But It doesn't work

Comment: What is location of above .htaccess? Are mod_rewrite and .htaccess enabled?

Comment: mod_rewrite and .htaccess are enabled  the .htaccess files is on the root. I tried also to add the .htaccess in the directory pages. Please note that the direct redirect for the pages without variables works fine. Example: Redirect 301 /pages/fauna/index.asp /pages/fauna/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^IdF=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^pages/fauna/fauna\.asp$ /pages/fauna/fauna?id=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure this is **first rule** and there is no other .htaccess in your system.

Comment: I have solved the problem. I add an .htaccess file in the /pages directory with this code:

 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^IdF=([^&]+) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^flora/flora\.asp$ /pages/flora/flora?id=%1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

If you're on IIS - which you must be if you're using Classic ASP -  then .htaccess doesn't do anything, (unless you have a third party ISAPI rewrite filter installed)

If you're using IIS7 or IIS8 you can add the rewrite rule in your web.config file

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: I use apache, I have to redirect the old classic ASP pages to the new PHP pages on apache.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I suppose one workaround would be to configure Apache to treat files with the .asp extension as php files, then redirect with a php command - I think php uses header('Location: ' . $youtargeturl);

Answer (score 0):

Dont get crazy, just redirect all the .asp request to a php script, and create a router in php, and then handle all the parameters and do what you need in a much more programmer-friendly way.

Take a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20631702/2357411)